# Can width and height be zero in drawing routines?

Tags: android, android-layout

Today I received a crash report because in the following snippet `w` and/or `h` are zero. I override `dispatchDraw` on my custom `ViewGroup` to draw an overlay after the children are drawn:

```
@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
  int w = getWidth();
  int h = getHeight();
  bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  // ...
}
```

I carefully read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Layout) and honestly can't understand why I should bother with the view size, because when the system requests the drawing, all Views must already have been laid out (and it doesn't make sense to draw a view if a size is zero). Moreover, this bug is difficult to track down because I can't reproduce it and because I only have 2 crash reports in more than 200k downloads. What's wrong and how can I recover it?

**READ THIS** I know the problem is that widht and height are 0. The question is **why they are zero after the tree has been laid out**. Every drawing piece of code needs primitive information like width and height, so it's silly that I must check for them to be non-zero every time I override `onDraw` or `dispatchDraw`. This should be handled by the system, and most of the time it is since I have never been able to reproduce this bug and only got two crash reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they can. There is no safe guard against width or height being equal to zero. So, when one uses them to compute coordinates to draw, must pay attention and check for valid dimensions.

Actually, since a View with a width/height equal to zero has really no room to show anything, I use this simple piece of code to skip the drawing routines

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0)
    return;
  // rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`    if the width or height are <= 0 

Read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29

you must use a `try{}catch(){}` statement

Comment: Yes, this is obvious. I asked **why** width and height are zero in the routine call

Comment: it's a design by contract rule. and if you override onDraw() and dispatchDraw(), you must do all the work they are designed to.

Comment: I can't find this *contract* anywhere. The doc doesn't state that you must `requestLayout` before drawing and, above all, it doesn't make sense to check the sides for zeroes, because the system should simply skip the drawing at all. In fact this bug hardly ever happens and I'm not able to reproduce it. Try it yourself

Comment: The contract is the method specification. In this case the contract says: three Parameters: width, height, config and, if width and/or height <= 0 , throw IllegalArgumentException. This was a choice of the method designer. I don't know why he/her decided for this behaviour (maybe to protect the method itself from unwanted divide by zero fault), but if you want to use that method, you need to respect the contract. Here a good explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the point yet. I'm not discussing about the bitmap, I am talking about drawing. Other statements will fail in the drawing routines (division by 0) because they don't expect width/height to be zero. I could certainly check for this at the beginning, but this would only mask bad API usage